# iOS take pictures in album and then show them

Tags: ios, image, alassetslibrary

What would be the best way in iOS 7 to take pictures inside a custom album (Named after my application) and then show the custom album.

I mean, I could add those pictures in a group using `AssetsLibrary` but there's some way to show them afterwards without having to create a custom gallery?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html the sample app is included. take a look

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please summarize the contents of the link in your answer, so that just in case the link goes down in the future, your answer would remain relevant.